# Tomcat7 REST Service with Basic Authentification XMLHttpRequest

Tags: rest, tomcat, basic-authentication

I'm just setting up a small TestScenario. I'm exposing a REST Service on Tomcat 7 with Jersey. The service is called by another Javascript/HTML5 Application via XMLHttpRequest.
For testing I just run the REST Service inside my eclipse installation with Tomcat.

Calling the REST Service from JavaScript works fine without any authentication setup.

Now I'm trying to add Basic Authentication mechanism to my REST Services. In the web.xml of my  web project i added

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>ImageLinksServices</display-name>
      <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.xxx.xxx.services</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>readonly</param-name>
                <param-value>false</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>



        <filter>
            <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
                <param-value>*</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
                <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
                <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
                <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
                <param-value>10</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

        </filter-mapping>

        <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                <http-method>GET</http-method>
                <http-method>POST</http-method>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>tomcat1</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>

            <user-data-constraint>
                <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
                <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
            </user-data-constraint>
        </security-constraint>

        <login-config>
            <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        </login-config>
    </web-app>
```

Calling the REST URL from Browser works fine. He asks for user and password then the Response of the REST service is displayed.

But when i try to call it from a Javascript with the following snipplet i receive always a 403 error and a warning that

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:10080/xxxx/rest/fileupload No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access
```

Code Snipplet i'm currently using:

```
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
//xhr.open("POST", url, true, "user1", "tomcat1");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic "+ btoa("user1:tomcat1"));
xhr.withCredentials = "true";
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        if(xhr.status == 200){
            var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

What I'm doing wrong ? I'm totally confused why now after adding authentication the Browser complains about  No Access Control Header is present. Before adding authentication to the service the call works also with CORS.

What I can see from the HTTP Request that the Basic Authentication Header seems to be set correctly.

```
    Request URL:http://localhost:10080/xxx/rest/fileupload
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Authorization:Basic dXNlcjE6dG9tY2F0MQ==
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:10080
Origin:http://localhost:63342
Referer:http://localhost:63342/xxx/html/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Thu, 05 Dec 2013 12:58:46 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Can anyone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong. I confused if a Tmocat configruation is mssing or my Javascript is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you managed to resolve your issue, but I ran into the same problem and debugged through the `org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter` to figure out why the request was being forbidden.

According to the [W3 CORS Spec Section 6.2 Preflight Requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests), the preflight must reject the request if any header submitted does not match the allowed headers.

The [default configuration for the CorsFilter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) `cors.allowed.headers` (as is yours) does not include the `Authorization` header that is submitted with the request.

I updated the `cors.allowed.headers` filter setting to accept the `authorization` header and the preflight request is now successful.

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>     
</filter>
```

Comment: Thanks, for your response. It works ! I added the Authorization header to the allowed headers, and now it works . Great.